# better way to do this in c++? std::string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to c++ and learning about std:string but i can't help but think there is a better way of doing this below...

```
BYTE a = 0x01;
BYTE b = 0x02;
BYTE c = 0x03;
WORD d = 0xFF;
char* e = "a char!";

std::string myString;

myString.append(a, 1);
myString.append(b, 1);
myString.append(c, 1);
myString.append(d, 2);
f = strlen(e);
myString.append(e, f);
```

Is there a faster and better way of doing something like the above in visual c++?

i am using visual studio 2010 and must use variables, any help appreciated!

Comment: did you mean `const char* e = "a char!";` ?

Comment: Would you mind telling us why you want to store such non printable characters in a "string"?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) to accomplish this. Something like the following should work.

```
std::string myString("\x01\x02\x03\xffa char");
```

If you need to initialize the string from variables you can use C++11's brace initialization syntax.

```
char a = 0x01;
char b = 0x02;
char c = 0x03;
char d = 0xFF;
const char* e = "a char!";

std::string myString{ a, b, c, d};
myString += e;
```

Comment: nice example, but i must use variables with it.

Comment: That kind of information _really_ needs to be included in your question.